# SLOW running query in MS access

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

What causing this query to execute long time. Is sub query block creating a mess?

```
SELECT WD.IdentityUserID, WD.Email, AD.mail
FROM WD INNER JOIN AD ON WD.IdentityUserID = AD.GGDComputerUserId
WHERE (((AD.mail) Not In (SELECT EMAIL FROM WD)));
```

Comment: Passthrough or Jet query? As backend is PostgreSQL passthough should be way faster. All criteria fields (WD.IdentityUserID, AD.GGDComputerUserId, WD.Email, AD.mail) are indexed? Check execution plan in postgresql,

Comment: This is a MS access Jet query.

Comment: [Create a pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42) to improve performance. [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/bb188204(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) provides further information. Even both links refer to SQL Server, they also apply to most other RDBMS (like PostgreSQL or MySQL/MariaDB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that for every record of the INNER JOIN you are looping over all the records of the WD table.

```
SELECT WD.IdentityUserID, WD.Email, AD.mail
FROM WD 
INNER JOIN AD ON WD.IdentityUserID = AD.GGDComputerUserId
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT EMAIL FROM WD WHERE EMAIL = AD.mail);
```

Comment: Not much difference. Both the table has 50 thousands records. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. What was the difference between your code and my suggestion in? More than 1 sec?

Comment: @santhosha . . . You accepted this answer, which discourages anyone else from trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to help but you may try to reduce the size of "right side" of join by filtering out the emails beforehand:

```
SELECT  
 WD.IdentityUserID,  
 WD.Email,  
 T.mail  
FROM WD  
INNER JOIN  
 (  
    SELECT
     mail,  
     GGDComputerUserId     
    FROM AD  
    WHERE  
     mail Not In (SELECT EMAIL FROM WD)  
 ) T  
ON WD.IdentityUserID = T.GGDComputerUserId;
```

(In case if query is already being optimized for that, then this would make no difference though)

Comment: Don't see a much difference